# Rewriting dynamic URL ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I know how to rewrite url into `web.conf` but the problem is that I have to know from the id given in the url wich name to put into the rewrited url for example
foo/5  should be foo/bar because in the database the id 5 have the name "bar"
i also have the class method that tell me which name is assignd the witch id 
So, I want to call the class from web.config to take the exact name for the corresponding id and then rewrite the URL
I saw the possibility of using `custom configuration class` but do not know how to use it.

Could you please tell me how or give me one other suggestion?

Comment: Last time I did something like this, I ended up writing my own IHttpModule, which intercept the requests, and rewrites the path based on some conditions, lookups and such.

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The general concept is that I take an incoming url (request) and map that to a specific page. Like `/blog/my-awesome-post` will be rewritten to `Blog.aspx?id=5`.

```
public class UrlRewriteModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() 
    {
        // perform cleanup here if needed.
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest); // attach event handler for BeginRequest event.
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // get the current context.
            HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;

            // the requested url
            string requestedUrl = context.Request.Path; // e.g. /blog/my-awesome-post

            // if you want to check for addtional parameters from querystring.
            NameValueCollection queryString = context.Request.QueryString;

            // perform db calls, lookups etc to determine how to rewrite the requested url.             
            // find out what page to map the url to.
            // lets say that you have a page called Blog, and 'my-awesome-post' is the title of blog post with id 5.
            string rewriteUrl = "Blog.aspx?id=5";

            // rewrite to the path you like.
            context.RewritePath(rewriteUrl);
    }
}
```

You would need to add the module to the modulelist in web.config:

IIS pre version 7.:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
          <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="Assembly.Name.UrlRewriteModule, Your.Namespace.Here" />
           ....
     </httpModules>
     .....
</system.web>
```

IIS 7 and newer:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
          <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="Assembly.Name.UrlRewriteModule, Your.Namespace.Here" />
          ....
     </modules>
    ....
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks for your response :) have you other solution that uses web.config for rewriting the urls?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to rewrite foo/bar to /foo/5 dynamically from web.config. I guess that would require you to manually add new routes whenever you need. Which would be time consuming and not a viable option if you have a lot of rules.